# Facebook Share URL having hash

Tags: facebook, url, share

My single page website has some products, and product details appear as simple pop-up when clicked. For each product there is Facebook share. But when I Facebook-share the url say `www.example.com#product1` in the shared url the `#product1` get stripped.

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'http://example.com/#product1',
}, function(response){});
```

When I share it comes as only http://example.com/   , not http://example.com/#product1.   I want the full URL to be shared like http://example.com/#product1. Its getting stripped off somehow.

How to avoid this?

Comment: Please also provide some piece of code.

Comment: You need an individual URL for each individual piece of content you want to share. (A different hash does not make them different URLs; the hash is a purely client-side construct.)

Comment: @sasha: I dont think I requires code to explain. When I share the url in facebook I need like this www.example.com#product1 .   But this only comes as www.example.com . The #product1 get stripped when shared in Facebook.

Comment: @CBroe : Can I make #product1 appear somehow in the shared URL or does facebook doesnot allow that ?

Comment: If you share a URL on Facebook with a fragment identifier (the part following `#`), then Facebook does keep it. I'm not sure why the other comments are saying otherwise, maybe they are out-of-date?

Answer (score 5):

Like CBroe mentions, Facebook indexes URLs and the `#` is not considered part of the URL.

A solution is to use "hashbang" `#!` notation instead. Facebook follows the [Google Ajax Specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) to allow indexing of, in this case, Ajax websites.

The effect is that `http://www.example.com/#!/product1` will be rewritten and instead the query to your server becomes `http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/product1`. In turn, you can catch that on your server and reply with a page dedicated to that product.

You can read a more elaborate answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15024853/561485

The most important part is that your website should be able to provide dedicated pages for each product; if you only have index pages, using the `#` notation will always share the same url.

Comment: If you share a URL on Facebook with a fragment identifier (the part following #), then Facebook does keep it.

Answer (score 2):

Now Facebook and Twitter doesn't allow sharing of URL's containing `#` tag. However you can share URL by using `%23` instead of `#`

```
<a class="twitter-share" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.goparties.com/%23/party/{{id}}" target="_blank">
```

Comment: If you share a URL on Facebook with a fragment identifier (the part following #), then Facebook does keep it.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I thought exactly the same, but sadly it's not a way to it :(

Answer (score 1):

You can also escape the url with `encodeURIComponent`

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: encodeURIComponent('http://example.com/#product1'),
}, function(response){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on needs and how it is being implemented, it can be done using a goo.gl API to generate a unique shareable link.

Two ways of implementing it is as follow:
1. Manually, just go to goo.gl and post your full link including #hash_tag (it will be shareable through Facebook)
2. Using API for automated share tasks... such as application etc, using the goo.gl url shorter API.

Answer (score 0):

The share dialog now supports the hashtag parameter

```
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
    hashtag: '#facebook'
  }, function(response){});
```

see the fb docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/