# Open Graph Protocol in Backbone Application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, seo, facebook-opengraph

I have a backbone application built on an Express JS API and Backbone JS frontend.

Every model and collection, thus consumes from the API, and I render them into the templates provided by a backbone view.

My attempt is this : Everytime the route changes (In turn, rendering a new view) I would like to change contents of the header tag - OGP related content, twitter cards, meta tags that help in SEO. I am not asking how to implement this, but this is the plan.

Are rumors true that OGP will not work this way? Do client side apps have no chance of having OGP entries which are dynamically changed by routes?

If yes, how should I change the way the app behaves without completely changing to server side rendering?

Comment: Check this post if you haven't already:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896773/opengraph-on-ajax-based-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most OGP libraries will only parse HTML and not execute JavaScript. So the only way to go is server side rendering.

React has libraries like [Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) which helps with this. You can take inspiration from it to build it on Backbone.

Comment: One Year Later >>> Moves to React Redux server side rendering. HEHEHE.